# How to get the files that are mapped to standard out/err?

Tags: java

When my Java program is launched, the standard out and err are redirected to some specific files, using a command like the following (unix) :

```
> java org.company.MyClass 1>/path/to/some/file 2>/path/to/err/file
```

Is there a way to read this info from within the Java program ? My requirement is to write a file in the same directory as the standard output.

The unix script is actually a script to start a java batch program. The Java program itself uses log4j, but logs onto the console, thus the logs are finally written to these files. I cannot specify a file appender in the log4j config because the path to the file is determined by the unix script, not by the Java program. Ideally, the unix script should generate the log4j config file that the Java program uses, but this is quite complex; this is not a possibility.

Comment: Why don't you just cd into the target directory before issuing your command?

Answer (score 1):

It not possible to do this because all you can retrieve is the file itself.  You can look for the file, but with hard links the file can appear in more than one directory.  If you need this solution I suggest you do

```
java org.company.MyClass /path/to/some/file /path/to/err/file
```

And use System.setOut and System.setErr to direct the output to the files.  That way you will know their paths as well.

An alternative is to do this

```
java org.company.MyClass /path/to/some 1>/path/to/some/file 2>/path/to/err/f
```

Answer (score 0):

If your program cares about filenames, you should provide the output and error files as arguments to the program, rather than redirecting stdout and stderr.

After all, it's entirely possible that your program could be run *without* redirecting output - in which case where would you want to write this extra file?

Comment: I would even go as far as say it would be better to remove the System.out and System.err usages all together and replace them by usages of a logging framework

Comment: @Robin: It depends what the output is, but yes, quite possibly. That wouldn't help with the "where do I put the other file" problem, of course :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this, since this is the UNIX shell who treats this. There is no UNIX tool I know of who is capable of doing what you propose.

You should be redirecting output WITHIN your java program itself by using a logging framework or (lower-level) setting System.err and System.out to be a FileOutputStream. You can then specify this "stdout file" by using an argument, which you can recover within your java program.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use stdout / srderr.

Use a configurable logging framework (jog4j, java.util.logging, etc.) and configure file-appender. Otherwisem you may create huge logfiles and have to stop you application, if you want to delete the file (if they are locked).